# Is it possible to cross Luxembourg north to south hiking?

Tags: hiking, luxembourg

I've recently realised that the distance from Clervaux to Luxembourg City is walkable in a two-day hike.

While I am aware that this is not exactly crossing the country from the northernmost point to the southernmost point, I am still interested in trying it.

The only thing is that I don't know of the existence of trails that could connect the two places (Ideally with a stop in Vianden). Google maps suggests walking on the road. While I don't mind walking on the road for a little while, I certainly prefer to be on hiking trails in the country.

Is there a network of trails that would enable me to do this?

Comment: Any special reason to go to Luxembourg specifically? I think walking the Mosel valley all the way to Schengen could also be a very interesting goal.

Comment: The facility of transportation. I will depart from Paris with a TGV to Luxembourg City, and inside luxembourg the transportation is easy and free. Plus, my friend has never seen the city of Luxembourg.

Comment: In that case, I think there is a bus from Schengen to Luxembourg and trains to Wasserbillig that could be an option.

Comment: Won't you need a visa to enter Schengen...  *oh, wait*.

Comment: NB, Google Maps is wholly unsuitable for planning hiking.  Try Openrouteservice, hiking.waymarkedtrails.org, Komoot, or proper hiking maps (the former two are free, the latter two cost money).

Comment: mapy.cz offers me three options of routes mostly using marked tourist trails. Just don't use Google, it's crap for this - the map graphics is also completely terrible for anything outdoors.

Comment: I don't use Google Maps for checking hiking trails (I have another app for that). I only used it to measure the distance between the points.

Comment: @embedded_dev Google is good for fast rough estimation as you've found.  It only occasionally routes down something totally unsuitable, an even that isn't too bad unless the detour is significant.  On the other hand it misses a lot of legitimate hiking paths.  So a useful preliminary tool

Comment: Not sure about your question but it is quite easy to walk across the border into France... so easy that you might not know you are in France for an hour or so and walk into a small shop and seem drunk.

Comment: Google doesn't understand trails.  Once you're off the road it just draws a line from the closest point it could reach to the destination.  There are multiple reports of people trying to follow such "directions" and being put in considerable peril.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [GR5 crosses Luxembourg North to South](https://www.visitluxembourg.com/fr/adresse/walking/randonnee-europeenne-en-etapes-gr5-e2), mostly along the Eastern border with Germany and the Mosel valley. Vianden is on this route, Luxembourg is not. From Echternach or Beaufort, you could however use some part of the [Mullerthal trail](https://www.mullerthal-trail.lu/en) routes to get quite close to Luxembourg. You could consider using some other form of transportation for the last 15-20 km between Bourlingster and the city.

Alternatively, walking all the way to Schengen along the Mosel valley would seem like a worthwhile goal in many ways. You could also stop in Wasserbillig to catch a train to Luxembourg. The distance would however be longer and maybe more suitable for a three-day or four-day trip.

Answer (score 9):

There are apparently numerous long-distance hiking trails in Luxembourg, including the trans-european E2 and E3 trails (although neither of these go to Luxembourg city). However, there appears to be no trail that covers the specific route you seek to do. You could however complete your journey by combining several different waymarked routes, although as they are not entirely direct, it may take you longer than two days.

There is a map of waymarked long distance trails at https://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/#?map=10!49.8017!6.1476
Although for your purposes there is a notable gap between Ettlebrook and Mersch that you would have to either go around, or fill in with hiking trails or roads that do not form part of a long distance route.

I have no personal experience of Luxembourg hiking, so cannot speak to how the signage or condition of these routes are, or what maps would be most useful for navigation.

Answer (score 7):

I have hiked in Luxembourg and the country is perfectly suitable for it. On the long distance trails as well as away from them.

Do realize that most of the trails will take longer than road routes and that many of the roads can get traffic heavy for their size.

I also never hiked near Luxembourg city, more in the north, Wiltz-Clervaux area and in the east, around Echternacht.

The country is not as public transport heavy as some of its neighbours but many places can be reached by bus or train if hiking takes longer than planned.

Answer (score 5):

Just opening mapy.cz (which  just uses the Openstreetmap data in that area, but in a graphical way I really like) shows a very dense network if hiking trails in Luxembourg. Some go along roads, some not. Sometimes you have a choice between a pilgrimage route that mostly uses roads (like [Jakobsweg](https://www.visitluxembourg.com/de/ansicht/walking/etappenwanderweg-saint-jacques-de-compostelle) that is going through Vianden) or hiking trails that go more across the hills. Depending on whether you want to follow one particular numbered trail or you wheter you do not mind to follow some more complicated plan, you have plenty of options. E.g., [this kind of route](https://en.mapy.cz/turisticka?planovani-trasy&x=6.1838054&y=49.6383501&z=13&rc=96HODxXnUI96abUxXPWA96h9zxXDP-f84xWnUklHsxWWSd96WuRxVLvb&rs=osm&rs=coor&rs=osm&rs=osm&rs=osm&rs=osm&ri=1149&ri=&ri=136453039&ri=2019&ri=2019&ri=136391365&mrp=%7B%22c%22%3A132%7D&xc=%5B%5D) mostly avoiding roads.